# Update csv file from shinyapp

Tags: r, csv, updates, shiny

I am building one Application using "shiny" package in R. I am passing the path of input .csv file into textInput component which is getting loaded into Dataframe at serverside. Now I want to apply sequence of operation on this data like convert to lowercase, remove punctuation and write it back to .csv file.

can anybody tell me how it is doable in R?

Comment: Use `write.csv` or something similar. Without a reproducible example it is hard to say much more. I assume you want to write the file server side?

Comment: Well whatever file I will pass, its attribute get displayed at UI side using uiOutput - Checkbox form. And list of operation as dropdown (Convert to lowercase, Remove Punctuations etc.). Now I will select  attribute one by one and apply appropriate operation on it. I will do same until the whole csv file is cleaned and final cleaned csv file I want to write back.  I have tried write.csv but when i apply next operation previous operation's result is undone. So can you please tell me the way to solve this?? I am little new to shiny.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue you are having. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example